# Encender y apagar el micrófono de un ordenador mediante código java

Tags: java

he estado buscando como apagar y encender el micrófono de un ordenador mediante código java pero no he tenido éxito. agradeceré mucho su cooperación al darme información o un ejemplo simple.

Gracias por su tiempo y saludos.

Comment: ¿Que has intentado?

Comment: Seria de utilidad que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), una vez que lo hagas, plantea nuevamente tu pregunta para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Me imagino que será para Android, la configuración del micrófono es global así que solo puedes "bloquear" el uso exclusivo del microfono. Para manejar el micrófono dispones de la clase [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html)